# How can I import a scala class into another using gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

note: I am new to gatling and know almost nothing about Scala.

I am starting the process of converting my load tests from Jmeter to gatling.  And I am stuck on how to organize the code base. All the examples that I have been able to find are single file examples.

How can import code from one simulation class into another?

I have this class and test scenario working now:

```
    package default

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class createGuestUser extends Simulation {


    val userPrefix = System.getProperty("userPrefix", "gatling_load_test") + "_" + scala.util.Random.nextInt + "_"
    val password = System.getProperty("password", "1234567")
    val hostname = System.getProperty("hostname", "http://0.0.0.0")
    val blank_headers = Map("Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")


    val httpConf = http
        .baseURL("http://0.0.0.0")

    object GetClientToken {     
        val slash = exec(http("Slash")
        .get("/")
        .headers(blank_headers)
        .check(regex("""var appToken = '(.*)';""").find.saveAs("xGlooApplication")) // var appToken = '60e5814d-9271-43b4-8540-157d1c743651';       
        )
    }
.....
```

And when I try to import the class into another simulation like this:

```
    package default

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

import createGuestUser._

class createAccount extends Simulation {
```

I get the following error when trying to import.

> 08:33:57.952 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ -
>   /Users/dclements/Dev/Gloo/load_testing/gatling/src/createAccount.scala:9:
>   not found: object createGuestUser 08:33:57.954 [ERROR]
>   i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - import createGuestUser._

Comment: i would suggest to start class name from upper case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to make compiler happy,

amend declaration:
`class createGuestUser extends Simulation`

to:
`object createGuestUser extends Simulation`

and then you can:

```
import default.createGuestUser._
```

Simulations should not be dependent each other. I would extract common code to separate classes e.g. SimulationSetup, ...Scenario

Comment: I would not use default package but in e.g. simulations.

Answer (score -1):

Check the [advanced tutorial](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/advanced_tutorial.html) from the official documentation. There's also a link to sources at the end of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But the advanced tutorial does not start to break apart the test suite into multiple files.  For example: It would be great if I could re-use the Browse object in another unrelated scenario.

Comment: Maybe it used to have this use case in the docs?  http://gatling.io/docs/1.5.6/user_documentation/tutorial/advanced_usage.html

Comment: I got it working following the instructions from the previous gatling docs on advanced usage.  If you change your answer to point there I'll accept it.

Comment: @digidigo you can answer your own question, too. I'd love to see your solution, since I'm running into the same problem.